# How to incorporate directory names when uploading a file to google cloud storage in node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

In my express server I have created a page to upload image files from a local machine.  It creates a temporary directory path in my root directory that is specified by the form data from the upload page.  I am trying to pass in the temporary directory names in the image upload, but no matter what I do it only uploads `image.jpg` instead of `category/subcat/image.jpg`, giving no organization to the bucket it is being uploaded to.

The form looks like:

```
  <form action="/upload" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="category" autocomplete="off"/>
      <input type="text" name="subcat" autocomplete="off"/>
      <input type="file" id="img" name="image" accept="image/*"/>
      <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>
```

With my code (using `fs` and `multer`) I create a directory path that looks like:

```
./category/subcat/image.jpg    //the names are dynamically generated by the form data
```

This is what I want the file to look like when it is added to the bucket.  However, when I upload, it is only uploading `image.jpg` and not `category/subcat/image.jpg`.
Here is the post request in the server file:

```
app.post("/upload", upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {
  let imagePath = `${req.body.categories}/${req.body.subcat}/${req.imageName}`

  async function uploadFile() {
      await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(imagePath)
    }
  uploadFile().catch(console.error);

  res.redirect("/upload#upload");
});
```

Any idea why the `uploadFile()` is not taking the full image path I am providing?  How can I amend the function to upload a file with it's directories?  No  matter what I add to `upload()` or how I define `imagePath` it only uploads `image.jpg` instead of `category/subcat/img.jpg`.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail what isn't working the way you expect.  When you say "uploadFile() is not taking the full image path", what is actually happening?  An error?  Something else?  Please be specific.

Comment: I mention a couple times the file/image name is the only thing being uploaded, but I want the file name plus the temporary directory names to be uploaded.

Comment: Could you edit the question to illustrate more clearly?  "only taking the image name" is not very clear to me.  You could provide a screenshot of what you observe, or find some way of explaining what you're observing that is more specific.

Comment: It is edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specify the destination path of the uploaded file, you will need to pass a second argument to [upload()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload), which is a [UploadOptions](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/global.html#UploadOptions) object.  You can see that it has a property called `destination`:

> The place to save your file. If given a string, the file will be
> uploaded to the bucket using the string as a filename. When given a
> File object, your local file will be uploaded to the File object's
> bucket and under the File object's name. Lastly, when this argument is
> omitted, the file is uploaded to your bucket using the name of the
> local file.

Since you are not providing a destination, it's taking the basename of the file you provided as the default.  You should simply provide the path name you want:

```
storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(imagePath, { destination: "path/you/choose.jpg" })
```